# Referencing enum inside of interface (API) project?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, software-design

For a while now, I've been working on two projects in a solution. `AppName` and `AppName.API`. API stores all my interfaces, while AppName stores everything else related to the solution.

I've reached a stage in my project where I'm not sure what I can do here. I need to reference an enum from `AppName` in a class in `AppName` but the class has an interface from `AppName.API`

This means that `AppName.API` has to have access to this enum. If I can't reference `AppName` in `AppName.API` what am I supposed to do?

Some suggested `AppName.Common`, but that also references `AppName.API` already so I can't reference that inside the API project. Do I really have to make an `AppName.Enums`

Comment: Have you considered putting the enums in the API with the interfaces? That would seem a sensible place.

Answer (score 1):

put it in AppName.API. Since you need it to be seen by you AppName.API project as well as AppName, then put it there.  Honestly, there can be a million ways to skin this cat.

Create a new project called "AppName.Enum" and put them all in there, then reference AppName.Enum in both AppName and AppName.API.

Comment: Keep in mind also, enums do not have to be hosted by a class. They can simply be implemented in the Namespace. Create a class file (.cs) in the AppName.API namespace, call it whatever you want (maybe Enums.cs), delete the class code out of it leaving just the Namespace, and create your enums there. Then anything that uses AppName.API will have access to them, including the classes in the AppName.API Namespace.

Comment: (continuing from Kevin's comment)...or better than that, keep each enum in a separate file so that each is independently version-controlled and easy to find.

Comment: I really hate contradicting the `AppName.API` project and butting not only interfaces but enums again, but I get where you're coming from. I have super OCD with this kind of things, but I think the best way is to put them inside a new project called `AppName.Enum`. Thanks to you all for your comments & answers.

Answer (score 1):

The structure that I usually use is an `AppName.Model` where you put all your models, enums, etc. Pure classes, nothing else.

Then you can reference this library from all other places. That means you'll be able to reference it from both `AppName.API`, `AppName` and `AppName.Common`.

Answer (score 1):

As M Moore put it "There can be a million ways to skin this cat".

The direction of you're approach is mainly driven by the objectives of the project, the resources required and the future of the project.

Here are 3 approaches:

i.) Loosely couple project layer - Layering used in complex business model/enterprise applications

```
AppName.Domain.Model
AppName.Domain.Enum
AppName.Domain.Constant
AppName.Data.Repository
AppName.Data.Service
AppName.Business.Logic
AppName.Business.Helper
AppName.Web
AppName.Api
AppName.Mobile.Android
AppName.Mobile.iOS
```

ii.) Common project layering - Layering used in many business applications

```
AppName.Domain
AppName.Data
AppName.Business
AppName.Shared
```

iii.) Monolith self contained project - Layering can be applied through folder structure

```
AppName
```

Comment: So your answer is to create `AppName.Enum`?

Comment: If the content of the project(AppName.Enum) needs to be shared across multiple projects, then yes creating AppName.Enum is a good approach